# Does Google App Engine (GAE) locally develop environment included the Memcached service?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, memcached

Does the Google App Engine local development environment include the Memcached service?

Must I connect the living Memcached service over the Internet even if I debug my PHP service in a local development environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The GAE development server simulates almost every feature of running your app live.

(With a few differences, including the fact that the local server won't enforce quotas or timeouts.)

This includes Memcached, or at least some sort of simulation of it. You don't need to connect to Google's actual Memcached server to test it locally. (There's no way to do that, regardless.)